# styling ant design tab header to look like radio buttons

Tags: reactjs, tabs, radio-button, antd

I am trying to modify the antd tab headers to look like radio buttons. Although the documentation of tabs at https://ant.design/components/tabs/ says that we can convert the tab headers into radio buttons, there is no implementation given. I have pasted below the antd code for tabs that i am trying to modify so that the tab headers will look like radio buttons.

```
 import { Tabs } from 'antd';

const { TabPane } = Tabs;

function callback(key) {
  console.log(key);
}

const Demo = () => (
  <Tabs defaultActiveKey="1" onChange={callback}>
    <TabPane tab="Tab 1" key="1">
      Content of Tab Pane 1
    </TabPane>
    <TabPane tab="Tab 2" key="2">
      Content of Tab Pane 2
    </TabPane>
    <TabPane tab="Tab 3" key="3">
      Content of Tab Pane 3
    </TabPane>
  </Tabs>
);

ReactDOM.render(<Demo />, mountNode);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure why you don't use [Radio Buttons](https://ant.design/components/radio/#components-radio-demo-radiogroup-with-name) directly instead. The doc states that you should use radio buttons for secondary tabs.

You can switch your content by using a state variable bound to the current radio group value.

Edit:

```
function renderContent(tab: number) {
  switch(tab) {
    case 1:
     return <div>Content 1</div>;
    case 2:
     return <div>Content 2</div>;
    case 3:
     return <div>Content 3</div>;
  }
}

const App = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(1);

  const onChange = e => {
    setValue(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Radio.Group onChange={onChange} value={value}>
        <Radio value={1}>Tab 1</Radio>
        <Radio value={2}>Tab 2</Radio>
        <Radio value={3}>Tab 3</Radio>
      </Radio.Group>
      <div>
        {renderContent(value)}
      </div>
    <div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, mountNode);
```

Comment: I am looking here for nav tabs which have radio buttons instead of tabs for toggling between tab panes. Can you provide how i can change the above snippet to my desired result?

Comment: See edit, hope this helps